# Another website using my company name

Tags: name

I have a quick question. I own the website Pokevault.com that I have been running for 10 years or so. The "pokevault" name I created and has become very popular. Today I found another website called "thepokevault.com". They are trying to use my name that I created for their own benefit. They sell similar Pokemon products. I do not have the Pokevault name trademarked, but is there anything I can do about this?

Thanks for your time
Brian Grabow

Comment: You should move this question to LawSE since it is about trademarks and not patents.

Answer (score 1):

If no other trademark has been filed, you can file a trademark now and use it then. Which the other person can also do and then forbid you from using your website.

(There might be some national law moderating this result, but from a trademark point of view, it's quite simple and I expect this to be true in many parts of the world.)